# I'm only allowing pubkey auth via ssh. How can I still log in with password?

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
egrep -i 'Pubkey|Password|Listen' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '^#'
    ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
    PermitRootLogin without-password
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

on an OpenBSD 5.1 server. But I can still login with FileZilla, and FileZilla only knows my password AFAIK (or not?).

How can I restrict any ssh/scp/sftp access to only accept key auth?

UPDATE: clinet side is a Scientific Linux 6.3, afaik the key is not cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your OS is Microsoft Windows, a SSH agent (like pageant) may have cached your key if you already connected your server using, for example, putty. see [this page on Filezilla wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#SFTP_using_SSH2%3a_Key_based_authentication) for details. So your server is probably setup as needed.

Comment: I updated the Q

Comment: There also is a ssh agent in Linux, you can test if your key is cached using "ssh-add -l" to have a list of cached keys

Comment: There is 1 key listed, so that means my key is cached? how can I clear this cache to test that filezilla really uses this?

Comment: a good idea is always to read documentation. You will quickly find what you are searching in "man ssh-add" :)